Select default selections select_group_ui
How would one select default options for select_group_ui from the datamods pacakge?
https://dreamrs.github.io/datamods/reference/select-group.html
For example, to select Audi, I tried passing the selected = "Audi" argument into vs_args but it doesn't seem to work.
library(shiny)
library(datamods)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
  # theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = 5L),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 10, offset = 1,
      tags$h3("Filter data with select group module"),
      shinyWidgets::panel(
        select_group_ui(
          id = "my-filters",
          params = list(
            list(inputId = "Manufacturer", label = "Manufacturer:"),
            list(inputId = "Type", label = "Type:"),
            list(inputId = "AirBags", label = "AirBags:"),
            list(inputId = "DriveTrain", label = "DriveTrain:")
          ), vs_args = list(disableSelectAll = FALSE)
        ),
        status = "primary"
      ),
      reactable::reactableOutput(outputId = "table"),
      tags$b("Inputs values:"),
      verbatimTextOutput("inputs")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  res_mod <- select_group_server(
    id = "my-filters",
    data = reactive(MASS::Cars93),
    vars = reactive(c("Manufacturer", "Type", "AirBags", "DriveTrain"))
  )
  
  output$table <- reactable::renderReactable({
    reactable::reactable(res_mod())
  })
  
  output$inputs <- renderPrint({
    attr(res_mod(), "inputs")
  })

}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui, server)


selected = NULL is hard-coded in select_group_ui, so passing it to vs_args won't work without further modifications.

What modifications would this be?
